# OTS parsing error: Unable to instantiate font face from font data

Tags: fonts, format, specifications, opentype

I have this data going into computing my [`cmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cmap) table:

```
{ version: { type: 'USHORT', value: 0 },
  numTables: { type: 'USHORT', value: 1 },
  platformID: { type: 'USHORT', value: 0 },
  encodingID: { type: 'USHORT', value: 6 },
  offset: { type: 'ULONG', value: 12 },
  format: { type: 'USHORT', value: 4 },
  cmap4Length: { type: 'USHORT', value: 34 },
  language: { type: 'USHORT', value: 0 },
  segCountX2: { type: 'USHORT', value: 4 },
  searchRange: { type: 'USHORT', value: 4 },
  entrySelector: { type: 'USHORT', value: 1 },
  rangeShift: { type: 'USHORT', value: 0 },
  end_0: { type: 'USHORT', value: 97 },
  end_1: { type: 'USHORT', value: 65535 },
  reservedPad: { type: 'USHORT', value: 0 },
  start_0: { type: 'USHORT', value: 97 },
  start_1: { type: 'USHORT', value: 65535 },
  idDelta_0: { type: 'SHORT', value: -97 },
  idDelta_1: { type: 'SHORT', value: 1 },
  idRangeOffset_0: { type: 'USHORT', value: 0 },
  idRangeOffset_1: { type: 'USHORT', value: 0 },
  glyph_0: { type: 'USHORT', value: 0 } }
```

The overall font file that gets generated is this:

```
00000000: 4f54 544f 0009 0008 0003 0001 4346 4632  OTTO........CFF2
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 009c 0000 0055 636d 6170  ...........Ucmap
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 00f4 0000 002e 6865 6164  ............head
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0124 0000 0036 6868 6561  .......$...6hhea
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 015c 0000 0024 686d 7478  .......\...$hmtx
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0180 0000 0004 6d61 7870  ............maxp
00000060: 0000 0000 0000 0184 0000 0006 6e61 6d65  ............name
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 018c 0000 0006 4f53 2f32  ............OS/2
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 0194 0000 0064 706f 7374  ...........dpost
00000090: 0000 0000 0000 01f8 0000 0020 0200 0500  ........... ....
                                         ^ ^  ^ ^
                                         | |  | |__________________ 0
                                         | |  |____________________ 5
                                         | |_______________________ 0
                                         |_________________________ 2 (start of CFF table)

000000a0: 171e 0a00 1f1e 0f1e 0f1e 0a00 1f1e 0f1e  ................
           ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |__________________ 30
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |____________________ 15
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_______________________ 30
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |_________________________ 31
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |____________________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |______________________________ 10
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_________________________________ 30
           | |  | |  | |  | |  |___________________________________ 15
           | |  | |  | |  | |______________________________________ 30
           | |  | |  | |  |________________________________________ 15
           | |  | |  | |___________________________________________ 30
           | |  | |  |_____________________________________________ 31
           | |  | |________________________________________________ 0
           | |  |__________________________________________________ 10
           | |_____________________________________________________ 30 /cff2/header/fontmatrix
           |_______________________________________________________ 23

000000b0: 0f0c 07aa 11cd 0c24 a818 da0c 2500 0000  .......$....%...
           ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |__________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |____________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_______________________ 0 /globalsubr count32
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |_________________________ 37  = op2 \cff2\header
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |____________________________ 12  = op1
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |______________________________ 218 = 139 + 79
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_________________________________ 24  = op
           | |  | |  | |  | |  |___________________________________ 168 = 139 + 29
           | |  | |  | |  | |______________________________________ 36  = op2
           | |  | |  | |  |________________________________________ 12  = op1
           | |  | |  | |___________________________________________ 205 = 139 + 66
           | |  | |  |_____________________________________________ 17  = op
           | |  | |________________________________________________ 170 = 139 + 31
           | |  |__________________________________________________ 7 \cff2\header\fontmatrix
           | |_____________________________________________________ 12
           |_______________________________________________________ 15

000000c0: 0000 0000 0000 0101 011d 95f7 3405 8b77  ............4..w
           ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |__________________ 119 = 139 - 20
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |____________________ 139 = 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_______________________ 5   = op 5
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |_________________________ 52  = 160 - 108
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |____________________________ 247 = int2
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |______________________________ 149 = 139 + 10
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_________________________________ 29 offset
           | |  | |  | |  | |  |___________________________________ 1 /charstring offsets
           | |  | |  | |  | |______________________________________ 1 /charstring offSize
           | |  | |  | |  |________________________________________ 1 
           | |  | |  | |___________________________________________ 0
           | |  | |  |_____________________________________________ 0
           | |  | |________________________________________________ 0 /charstring count
           | |  |__________________________________________________ 0
           | |_____________________________________________________ 0 /vstore length16
           |_______________________________________________________ 0

000000d0: 15db 9f05 3b8b 05db 8b15 3b77 058b c715  ....;.....;w....
           ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |__________________ 21 = op 21
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |____________________ 199 = 139 + 60
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_______________________ 139 = 139
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |_________________________ 5 = op 5
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |____________________________ 119 = 139 - 20
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |______________________________ 59 = 139 - 80
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_________________________________ 21 = op 21
           | |  | |  | |  | |  |___________________________________ 139 = 139
           | |  | |  | |  | |______________________________________ 219 = 139 + 80
           | |  | |  | |  |________________________________________ 5 = op 5
           | |  | |  | |___________________________________________ 139 = 139
           | |  | |  |_____________________________________________ 59 = 139 - 80
           | |  | |________________________________________________ 5 = op 5
           | |  |__________________________________________________ 159 = 139 + 20
           | |_____________________________________________________ 219 = 139 + 80
           |_______________________________________________________ 21  = op 21 

000000e0: db4f 058b c715 0000 0001 0101 048b 8b12  .O..............
           ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |__________________ 18 = op
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |____________________ 139 = 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_______________________ 139 = 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |_________________________ 4 /fontindex offsets
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |____________________________ 1 /fontindex offsets 
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |______________________________ 1 /fontindex offsize
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_________________________________ 1
           | |  | |  | |  | |  |___________________________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |______________________________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  |________________________________________ 0 /fontindex count
           | |  | |  | |___________________________________________ 21 = op 21 /charstring
           | |  | |  |_____________________________________________ 199 = 139 + 60
           | |  | |________________________________________________ 139 = 139
           | |  |__________________________________________________ 5 = op 5
           | |_____________________________________________________ 79 = 139 - 60
           |_______________________________________________________ 219 = 139 + 80

000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0006 0000 000c  ................
           ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |__________________ 12
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |____________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_______________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |_________________________ 0 /offset
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |____________________________ 6
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |______________________________ 0 /encodingID
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_________________________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  |___________________________________ 0 /platformID
           | |  | |  | |  | |______________________________________ 1
           | |  | |  | |  |________________________________________ 0 /numTables
           | |  | |  | |___________________________________________ 0
           | |  | |  |_____________________________________________ 0 /version
           | |  | |________________________________________________ 0
           | |  |__________________________________________________ 0
           | |_____________________________________________________ 0
           |_______________________________________________________ 0

00000100: 0004 0022 0000 0004 0004 0001 0000 0061  ..."...........a
           ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |__________________ 97
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |____________________ 0 /end_0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_______________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |_________________________ 0 /rangeShift
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |____________________________ 1
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |______________________________ 0 /entrySelector
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_________________________________ 4
           | |  | |  | |  | |  |___________________________________ 0 /searchRange
           | |  | |  | |  | |______________________________________ 4
           | |  | |  | |  |________________________________________ 0 /segCountX2
           | |  | |  | |___________________________________________ 0
           | |  | |  |_____________________________________________ 0 /language
           | |  | |________________________________________________ 34
           | |  |__________________________________________________ 0 /cmap4length
           | |_____________________________________________________ 4
           |_______________________________________________________ 0 /format

00000110: ffff 0000 0061 ffff ff9f 0001 0000 0000  .....a..........
           ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |__________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |____________________ 0 /idRangeOffset_1
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_______________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |_________________________ 0 /idRangeOffset_0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |____________________________ 1
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |______________________________ 0 /delta_1
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_________________________________ 159
           | |  | |  | |  | |  |___________________________________ 255 /delta_0
           | |  | |  | |  | |______________________________________ 255
           | |  | |  | |  |________________________________________ 255 /start_1
           | |  | |  | |___________________________________________ 97
           | |  | |  |_____________________________________________ 0 /start_0
           | |  | |________________________________________________ 0
           | |  |__________________________________________________ 0 /reservePad
           | |_____________________________________________________ 255
           |_______________________________________________________ 255 /end_1

00000120: 0000 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000  ................
           ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^  ^ ^
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |__________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |____________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_______________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |_________________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |____________________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |______________________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |  | |_________________________________ 1
           | |  | |  | |  | |  |___________________________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  | |______________________________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |  |________________________________________ 0
           | |  | |  | |___________________________________________ 1
           | |  | |  |_____________________________________________ 0
           | |  | |________________________________________________ 0
           | |  |__________________________________________________ 0 \cmap
           | |_____________________________________________________ 0
           |_______________________________________________________ 0 /glyph_0

00000130: 5f0f 3cf5 0003 03e8 0000 0000 d867 5bd6  _.<..........g[.
00000140: 0000 0000 d867 5bd6 0000 0000 005a 0000  .....g[......Z..
00000150: 0000 0003 0002 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000  ................
00000160: 00c8 0064 0000 005a 0000 0000 0000 0001  ...d...Z........
00000170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001  ................
00000180: 005a 0000 0000 5000 0001 0000 0000 0000  .Z....P.........
00000190: 0006 0000 0005 0000 0000 0000 0000 028a  ................
000001a0: 02bb 0000 008c 028a 02bb 0000 01df 0031  ...............1
000001b0: 0102 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 5858  ..............XX
000001d0: 5858 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  XX..............
000001e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0003 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000200: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000210: 0000 0000 0000 0000                      ........
```

Wondering if in that first JSON, everything looks good / conforms to the  spec. I am essentially just concatenating the decimal values from that JSON and then putting it into a Buffer and writing it to the file, so if that is accurate the final result should be accurate.

Not sure if the 255 values are correct yet, but otherwise I can't see anything that would make it incorrect yet. Wondering if you can find anything.

If I make a slight change in certain places, then I get:

```
OTS parsing error: cmap: Failed to parse table
```

But otherwise get:

```
OTS parsing error: cmap: Failed to serialize table
```

Not sure which one is closer or further from working.

If I change these two:

```
platformID: { type: 'USHORT', value: 3 },
encodingID: { type: 'USHORT', value: 1 },
```

I get:

```
OTS parsing error: Unable to instantiate font face from font data.
```

Comment: You're probably going to have to explain how you made your font (a lot of the values you show are computed values, not values you would ever need to write out yourself), as well as how you're running OTS, but independently of that, I can strongly recommending using [TTX](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) to build a similar CFF2 and seeing how it differs from what you came up with.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very generic error that encompasses many sub-errors. More information can be found with [fontbakery](https://github.com/googlefonts/fontbakery) or the [Mac Font Validator](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/09/using-os-xs-font-validator/), each which offer slightly different information. There are other projects too such as Microsoft Font Validator and OTS, but these ones offered significant debugging improvement.

Still haven't resolved the overall issue, but knowing better error messages helps restructure the problem.